# Wordpress Search throws Invalid Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I have a weird issue with my search function. If I search in the backend (in posts fx.) it works fine the first time, but if I do a second search on the 'already searched' item, it throws an Invalid Post Type. I have deducted that the problem is with my custom code, for the search function for my website. I cannot, however, find whatever is conflicting with the backend searching function. Anyone has a clue what is going wrong? The code is as follows:

Functions.php:

```
// Number of search results displayed
function change_wp_search_size($query) {
  if ( $query->is_search ) // Make sure it is a search page
      $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 6; // Change 10 to the number of posts you would like to show

  return $query; // Return our modified query variables
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'change_wp_search_size'); // Hook our custom function onto the request filter
```

The search function:

```
<?php if( have_posts() ): while( have_posts() ): the_post();?>


    <div class="individual-search">

    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()):?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="readmore">
            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('blog-small');?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>" class="img-fluid mb-3 img-thumbnail mr-4">


            <!-- <?php the_post_thumbnail(  'blog-small', [ 'class' => 'img-fluid mb-3 img-thumbnail', 'alt' => '<?php the_title();?>'] ); ?> -->

        <?php endif;?>

        <div class="blog-content search-results">

            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <?php the_excerpt();?>

            <span class="readmore-txt"><?php echo __('Read more', 'themedomain'); ?></span></a>


        </div>

    </div>

<?php endwhile; else: ?> 


 
<?php echo __('There is no results on the search', 'themedomain'); ?> <?php echo get_search_query();?>
 

    
<!--     There is no results on the search: '<?php echo get_search_query();?>' -->
    
<?php endif;?>
```

Search.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<section class="page-wrap">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="search-wrapper">

<!--         <h1>Search results for: <?php echo get_search_query();?></h1> -->

        <h1><?php echo __('Search results for', 'themedomain'); ?> <?php echo get_search_query();?></h1>

        <section class="search-flex">
        <?php get_template_part('includes/section', 'searchresults'); ?> 

</section>

<div class="pagination">
        <?php
        global $wp_query;

        $big = 9999999999; // Need an unlikely integer

        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
        ) );
        ?>
         <!-- Pagination -->
         
</div>

    </div>
</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Search form:

```
<form action="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>" method="get">
    <input type="hidden">
    <input placeholder="<?php echo __('Search...', 'themedomain');?>" type="text" name="s" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query();?>" required>
    <button type="submit"><?php echo __('Search', 'themedomain');?></button>
</form>
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated - I am very lost on what is causing this! (I have tested if plugins was the cause, and it seems that it is indeed something within the linked code).

Comment: Not sure if `$query->is_search` only applies to frontend searches? Try and make that condition `$query->is_search && !$query->is_admin`, to explicitly exclude any search made in the backend from the query manipulation.

Comment: What a simple solution - and works like a charm! That was exactly what was needed - and makes a lot of sense to exclude the admin search. Many thanks, now I don't have to pull out my hair editing backend posts!